# How do I make the first item from an array not be placed after a comma?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 buttons. One of them inputs text and saves it in an array, the other button shows the items in the array, and the other closes the items that was shown. When I click the second button after I saved some text in the first one, the text is shown but with a comma before it. When I input another piece of text in the first button and click the second button to show it, the previous item gets repeated. How do I avoid this?

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementById('password');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('saved_passwords');
const btn3 = document.getElementById('closed_passwords');
let passwords = [];
let text = '';

btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let chosen_password = prompt('Enter a Password');
  const save_password = prompt('Save? "Yes" or "No"')
  save_password == 'Yes' ? passwords.push(chosen_password) : alert('Kindly retry.');
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  passwords.forEach((passwords) => {
    text += ", " + passwords;
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = text;
  })
})
```

```html
<button id='password'>Add a password</button><br>
<button id='saved_passwords'>Show Saved Passwords</button><br>
<button id="close_passwords">Close Saved Passwords</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: Just do -> `innerHTML = passwords.join(", ")`

Comment: Also you cannot say no? And must write `Yes`?

Comment: Yes, as @mplungjan says `yes` and `Yes` or even `YES` etc, are not the same.  You might be better using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm  But even then, these dialogs are not great UI.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the index is zero:

```js
btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  text = '';
  passwords.forEach((password, index) => {
    text += (index > 0 ? ', ' : '') + password;
  })
  document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = text;
});
```

Or, better, you can use `Array.join` to put the commas between the strings:

```js
btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = passwords.join(', ');
});
```